# Potentiometer after NPN transistors

Tags: potentiometer, npn

I was looking to use a potentiometer to limit brightness for LED matrix. 
The problem I ran into is I would need a lot of potentiometers.
The Led matrix will be multiplexing so only one Led will be on at any given time.
I was wondering if the picture below is good to do. Are there any negative side effects of using a potentiometer this way ? [image]

Comment: Other than having to absorb *all* the current going through all the LED strings?

Comment: It is for Led multiplexing matrix only one Led will be on at a given time. I should have made that a little clearer above.

Comment: what are you using to pilot the transistor bases?

Comment: 74HC595 shift register.

Comment: If, and only if, you are driving only a single one of the transistors at a time then I agree with Andy below and think this will be fine. If you drive more than one then you are going to divide current and it likely wont work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each LED is connected in the collector of each transistor then I can't see a problem with what you suggest. You could also do it like this with FETs: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOGOgk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But, I think the circuit you have will be most appropriate for use with BJTs

Comment: Thank you for your help. I believe you have answered my question the best out of the answers given.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simulate the circuit, the LTspice circuit list is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3kqplsrvjsf9olm/LED%20dimmer%20interactions.asc). If not, and this     is what you're doing, then you should be fine:

[image]